# Coordinate Time and Proper Time/Simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time, reference-frames

At close to the speed of light, clock A is running slower than "stationary" clock B.  Does clock A enter the future time reference of clock B as it slows down?

Trying to understand where the forward motion of time comes from:  Associating with the twin paradox and guessing that one would not create a diagram of a vertical axis for coordinate time unless they were part of a larger coordinate time...If there only existed just two electrons with equal coordinate and proper time...What happens to future vs. present vs. past if one electron attaches to a hydrogen nucleus that suddenly appears?

Comment: Not sure what your question means.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to note is that speed is relative, Clock A would see clock B moving from A's point of reference, and B would see A moving in B's reference, so you shouldn't be using the word "stationary" in this context. Both the clocks would see the other clock tick slower, B would see A's future only if it returns back to A, this makes it obvious to A and to B they it was B who was moving (by turning around).
Also see [twin paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox)